# How to count total amount of comments per posts in nodejs, react js and sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I am working on a project where a user can ask and answer a question so in the comments filed I have trouble with it.
the comments table is working well and displaying the data and can delete the data, but I want to count the total number of comments per post.

These blooks of codes are working well but it counts all the comments in the table, that's what I don't want, I want to display the total number of each post not all the amount of the comments in one post.

```
    router.get("/commentsCounter/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const commentsCounter = await Comments.count(id);

  res.json({commentsCounter});
  console.log('commentsCounter', commentsCounter)
});
```

in the comment table, I have commentbody,author name, and postId.

Do any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code (DB call, what the select statement looks like etc) it's hard to say..

But, typically if you DB is setup to have say 'posts' and 'comments' tables and the comment table has something like id AND parentID (the ID of the parent POST in the 'posts' table) you should be able to do it fairly easily using javascript OR the DB query itself

If you are doing it on the DB side, you would typically add a COUNT to the select statement OR once you have the results of the query you can just do a 'length' of the returned object to get the total returned.

*** Edit ***

As @Pouya had pointed out, you can doing via the SQL query as show in his post, this will count the number of responses based on the select, this does require a query per though, again without knowing the full flow of this this may or may not be what you are looking for but would give you the count based on the specific query.

Now, if you are say, returning a large object of ALL replies and want to get just the responses for a specific subset you will want to look at filtering your return object by the right key/value

something like

```
let myArr = [{id:'123',name:'item1'},{id:'234',name:"item2"}, 
{id:'123',name:"item3"}]

//filter just id 123
// filter syntax is [array].filter(variable => [key you want to filter on].includes("[value to filter on]")
let newArray = myArr.filter(p => p.id.includes('123'));

//our new array

console.log(newArray)
```

Should get you just a subset of the array, then you can just do

```
let replyCount = newArray.length
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind reply I will post a pic of the DB, you can check it out,
and yes I am using MYSQL DB and, i have 2 tables (Posts) and (Comments).
I just want to display the total number of comments of each post under the post section.

Comment: Please take a look at the question again i edited it!

Comment: @john, I have updated the response to add some additional things to try out.

Comment: What I did is like this: -1 i declared a statement

const [commentsCounter, setCommentsCounter] = useState([]);

and: -2 geting by axios like this:

 useEffect(() => {
axios.get(`http://localhost:3007/comments/commentsCounter/${id}`).then((res) => {
      setCommentsCounter(res.data.commentsCounter);
    });
  }, []);

and then rendered 
{commentsCounter.length}
bu i got an empty array.

Comment: You may want to ensure that the data is being return from your get request first. So console.log the res AND the res.data AND res.data.commentsCounter to ensure you are actually getting the response back how you want. Once thing too ( I don't use axios personally but ensure the type is of JSON) so you also want to make sure the response is of type object and not string. Also not sure what the setCommentsCounter function does so its hard to say

Comment: Yes did and the result was 0:
Like this
setCommentsCounter 0

Comment: What about on the server itself, so on the route, add a console.log of what you a returning, does that show 0 records as well?

Comment: They it must be a an issue with your query, if that is returning 0 results then it returned 0 records. Once that is returning results it should pass that a long

Comment: I think so, it shows the result after I used Pouya's codes like this 
::
::
router.get("/commentsCounter/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  // const commentsCounter = await Comments.count(id);
  const commentsCounter = await Comments.count({ where: { postId: id} });

  res.json({commentsCounter});
  console.log('commentsCounter', commentsCounter)
});

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize [count](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-count) method takes an object as its argument which you can specify your post ID in its `where` attribute. So in your case you want to change your query to

```
const commentsCounter = await Comments.count({ where: { postId: id} });
```

Comment: Yes, I am thinking like this, i am agree with you, i tried this but I am a bit confused about the client-side, could you please clarify for me how to implement this in the front-end.
this the code for the front-end.

 useEffect(() => {
axios.get(`http://localhost:3007/comments/commentsCounter/${id}`).then((res) => {
      setCommentsCounter(res.data.commentsCounter);
    });
  }, []);

and rendering like this:

 {t("view_comments")} ({commentsCounter})

Comment: @john, again it depends on  how you are getting the data but if you are making a call to get comments as per your get request then the response from SQL should already be an object that will get sent back to the client. Once there you can just do a .length to get the total number of items in the JSON object OR if its contains more then just one posts responses filter based on the parent ID

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time in paying attention!
I am a bit new in Mysql that's why I got confused about this.
just if you can clear it or a complete example it would be really nice:)